# Error while using knife custom template

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I am trying to use knife custom template. The whole purpose is to get the chef-client installed using scp from a node where already chef-client package exsists , rather than downoading it from internet.

My custom template looks like this :

```
bash -c '

<%= "export https_proxy=\"#{knife_config[:bootstrap_proxy]}\"" if knife_config[:bootstrap_proxy] -%>
if [ ! -f /usr/bin/chef-client ]; then
  scp -r -i /root/auth_key username@<ip-where-package-is-present>:chef-11.4.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm /tmp
  rpm -Uvh /tmp/chef-11.4.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
fi

mkdir -p /etc/chef

cat > /etc/chef/validation.pem <<'EOP'
<%= validation_key %>
EOP
chmod 0600 /etc/chef/validation.pem

<% if encrypted_data_bag_secret -%>
cat > /etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret <<'EOP'
<%= encrypted_data_bag_secret %>
EOP
chmod 0600 /etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret
<% end -%>

<%# Generate OHai Hints -%>
<% unless @chef_config[:knife][:hints].nil? || @chef_config[:knife][:hints].empty? -%>
mkdir -p /etc/chef/ohai/hints

<% @chef_config[:knife][:hints].each do |name, hash| -%>
cat > /etc/chef/ohai/hints/<%= name %>.json <<'EOP'
<%= hash.to_json %>
EOP
<% end -%>
<% end -%>

cat > /etc/chef/client.rb <<'EOP'
<%= config_content %>
EOP

cat > /etc/chef/first-boot.json <<'EOP'
<%= first_boot.to_json %>
EOP

<%= start_chef %>'
```

However while running the below bootstap command

knife bootstrap ip-target --sudo -x user -i key --template-file /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef11.4.0/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/test_rhel.erb

I am getting following error
ERROR: TypeError: can't convert nil into String.

Please let me know what is it that I am missing.

Comment: Can you please post the full output of the command, including the error and stacktrace?